# Selecting a child node (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom, child-nodes

How can I select the 2nd `<a>` tag using pure Javascript?

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/page/2/">Prev</a>
    <a href="/page/4/">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple possibilities: `document.querySelectorAll('.navigation a')[1]`, `document.querySelector('.navigation').children[1]`, `document.querySelectorAll('.navigation a:nth-child(2)')`, `document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0].children[1]`. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the DOM selector [**getElementsByClassName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

***Return Value:*** an array of elements containing the class name.

Replace the `[?]` with the index of the target from the return value of the the `getElementsByClassName` selector. For example, if the the `<div>` tag containing the `<a>` tags was the first element of the document with the class name `navigation` then it would be at index `0` (since it's 0 based) of the return array, therefore you should use `[0]` for the corresponding element.

Use the [**.children**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property to return an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of the  child nodes (in this case `<a>` tags) of which their  parent node (in this case the  `<div>` tag).

//JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[1].children[1];
```

//HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/page/1/">Prev</a>
    <a href="/page/2/">Next</a> 
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/page/3/">Prev</a>
    <a href="/page/4/">Next</a> (selected element)
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/page/5/">Prev</a>
    <a href="/page/6/">Next</a> 
</div>
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/page/7/">Prev</a>
    <a href="/page/8/">Next</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why they downvoted? Or is this punishment for answering this question?

Comment: Using `getElementsByTagName` isn't specific at all, your selecting all the `<a>` tags in the whole document... as well as the drop in performance with   using a selector such as this one.

Comment: @JordanDavis, very good point. Thanks for pointing that out. Thanks for not being an anonymous downvoter.

Comment: Change it to `.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[?].children[1]` as @Xufox mentioned in the main thread, this would be the fastest way depending on how may elements are associated with the `navigation` class...  However I would recommend him using an `id` and direct selecting using `getElementById` but we don't have his full source so thats all we can say.

Comment: @JordanDavis, heh, thanks, and thanks again for the tip :)